# Query for only integers Rails 2.3

Tags: regex, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-2

My environment is `Ruby 1.8.7-p358 with Rails 2.3.11`.  I am trying to query for all `accounts` that have a `first_name` containing only numbers (they are all 3 digit integers, i.e. 001, 143, 815, etc.).  I have been trying to use this query:

```
Account.find(:all, :conditions => ["first_name LIKE ?", "[^0-9][^0-9][^0-9]"])
```

All I get in return is `=> []`.

If I use the same query only with `NOT LIKE` I get all `accounts`, including the ones where `first_name` is an integer.

I've also tried using:

```
Account.find(:all, :conditions => ["first_name REGEXP ?", "[^0-9][^0-9][^0-9]"])
```

but that only gives me:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "REGEXP"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "accounts" WHERE (first_name REGEXP '[0-9][0-9...
                                               ^

: SELECT * FROM "accounts" WHERE (first_name REGEXP '[0-9][0-9][0-9]')  ORDER BY first_name ASC
  from /Users/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@popcorn_recruiter_portal/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
  from /Users/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@popcorn_recruiter_portal/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:520:in `execute'
  from /Users/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@popcorn_recruiter_portal/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1002:in `select_raw'
  from /Users/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@popcorn_recruiter_portal/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:989:in `select'
  from /Users/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@popcorn_recruiter_portal/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `select_all_without_query_cache'
      from /Users/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@popcorn_recruiter_portal/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:62:in `select_all'
  from /Users/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@popcorn_recruiter_portal/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:665:in `find_by_sql'
  from /Users/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@popcorn_recruiter_portal/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:1582:in `find_every'
  from /Users/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@popcorn_recruiter_portal/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:619:in `find'
  from (irb):189
  from :0
```

Are regular expressions not allowed?  How am I able to find each `account` with a `first_name` that's equal to a three digit integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `like` operator does not evaluate regular expressions. In instead you can use both `similar to`:

```
select '980' similar to '[0-9][0-9][0-9]';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

Or `~`:

```
select '980' ~ '[0-9][0-9][0-9]';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Arrghh!  Still empties!  `>> a = Account.find(:all, :conditions => ["first_name ~ ?", " [0-9][0-9][0-9]"])
=> []
>> a = Account.find(:all, :conditions => ["first_name SIMILAR TO ?", " [0-9][0-9][0-9]"])
=> []`

Comment: @JustLikeThat There is a leading space in your " [0-9][0-9][0-9]"

Comment: You're right!  The operator `SIMILAR TO` worked great!  Thanks!